# authorized_keys ignored for new git user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys, authorized-keys

I want to create an own git server. I started with a `root` user and here is the following I did:

```
mkdir /srv/git/project.git
useradd -r -d /srv/git git
passwd git
```

Now I have a new user `git` (can log in via `su git` from my root account).

I want to login via `git@mywebsite.com` without the use of a password. Right now, it will ask for a password every time.

For root, I have my SSH public key in .ssh/authorized_keys. The key should also work for `git`. Do I have to add another authorized_keys file for this `git` user? With my `useradd` command, I do not create a home directory where I could add it, so where should it go?

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Nobody has an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log` and attempt to login once more from a different console. You will see now the lag that should tell you why exactly the login was denied.

In my case there were wrong permissions for the home folder.

Answer (score 0):

You **did** create a home directory, it just isn't sitting under `/home`.

`/srv/git`

Under that directory create a `.ssh` directory, fix the permissions:

- `mkdir /srv/git/.ssh`
- `chmod 0700 /srv/git/.ssh`

Create a new authorized_keys file with the public key in it, fix the permissions:

- `vim /srv/git/.ssh/authorized_keys  # or method of your choice`
- `chmod 0600 /srv/git/.ssh/authorized_keys`